# Android WebRTC JNI system error lookup: "last system error: 11"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, webrtc

I got an error message similar to this when doing some WebRTC NDK development on Android:

```
2019-02-04 13:20:35.987 10214-10246/com.my.package E/rtc: #
    # Fatal error in mypath/src/main/jni/src_code.cpp, line 124
    # last system error: 11
    # Check failed: !jni()->ExceptionCheck()
    # error during Class.function_call
    #
```

Given that the exception is buried under some layer of abstraction (WebRTC), the line that would be particular helpful here is `last system error: 11`. However, trying to find a description of this error has been a little tricky. [After](https://www.google.com/search?q=jni%20system%20error%20table&oq=jni%20system%20error%20table&aqs=chrome..69i57.3241j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) [doing](https://www.google.com/search?ei=-69YXLLSJaaxggfNqZCoCA&q=webrtc%20last%20system%20error%20table&oq=webrtc%20last%20system%20error%20table&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160l2.11000.11683..11824...0.0..0.219.950.0j4j1....2..0....1..gws-wiz.......33i299.a8e3vh8T54U) [some](https://www.google.com/search?ei=CbBYXLy4EuqFggfpraHIDA&q=webrtc%20last%20system%20error%20table%20%2211%22&oq=webrtc%20last%20system%20error%20table%20%2211%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l3.11981.12849..13108...0.0..0.332.1067.0j4j0j1....3..0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.3QikZMWWP5c) [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?ei=CbBYXLy4EuqFggfpraHIDA&q=webrtc%20last%20system%20error%20table%20%2211%22&oq=webrtc%20last%20system%20error%20table%20%2211%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l3.11981.12849..13108...0.0..0.332.1067.0j4j0j1....3..0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.3QikZMWWP5c), I couldn't seem to find anything. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place for a more meaningful description of this error? Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever you've tried to do ...the terminal says:

```
$ perror 11
OS error code  11:  Resource temporarily unavailable
```

`src_code.cpp, line 124` would be required to interpret it in a meaningful way.

most likely some trying to access some resource, which had not been opened.

Comment: Thanks! perror looks like what I need. Is there anything I need to add to my path to use perror? 


```
4563:NativeSDKExamples zmatthews$ which perror
4563:NativeSDKExamples zmatthews$ perror 11
-bash: perror: command not found
```

Comment: `yum whatprovides perror` tells me, that it comes from `MariaDB-server`. there are further variations of that command: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/error.3.html

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h ...actually it's `EAGAIN`; "try again"; while "resource temporarily unavailable" sounds rather official, providing a little more clue.